# Converting a WindowsPhone Application Page to a UserControl

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-8, user-controls, windows-phone

Good day, In Visual Studio, when creating a new UserControl, you don't have the Windows Phone frame background as a visual guide to position views correctly as you would, When creating a new Windows Phone Application Page. Is there a way to enable this when creating a new UserControl or better still, How can i change an Existing Windows Phone Application Page into a UserContro?

What i mean is this:

1. Create a new Windows Phone Application Page.
2. Design and position Views accordingly in it.
3. Convert the WindowsPhoneApplication Page to a UserControl.

the reason i need this is because i would be switching between page layouts and a good solution(as far as i know), is to turn them to a UserControl. Thanks in advance for your input.

Comment: By page layout do you mean PageOrientation?

Comment: Entire frame can't be converted into UserControl. Also, page will be a top level container (after frame) to host different controls. It would be a better idea to have separate user controls and you can switch them by adding/removing from main layout (in the same page) rather than navigating through pages. This will give you desired output.